# OpenSSL Decryption using a Key.txt and IV.txt file

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl, cryptography

Working with a client to set up OpenSSL file encryption. They've sent us an encrypted file (I'll call it *sample.encrypted*), along with key and iv files (*key.txt* and *iv.txt*).

- The contents of the *key.txt* file look like this:

  ```
  KEY: [string of 32 characters]
  ```
- The contents of the *iv.txt* file look like this:

  ```
  IV: [string of 16 characters]
  ```

I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, and learned that OpenSSL doesn't come installed by default with Windows (apparently it's primarily used by Linux users?)

So, I've downloaded and installed a 64-bit OpenSSL package from here:
(https:)//slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Specifically, the "Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.2d Light" build found here:
(https:)//slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_0_2d.exe

Once installed, I had to manually configure my environment variable for the OpenSSL config files as such (from the command prompt):

```
    set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.cfg
```

I verified that the path information above was correct, and that the environment variable had stuck, and then attempted to run the following command:

```
    openssl enc -d -K key.txt -iv iv.txt -in sample.encrypted -out sample.decrypted
```

This was based on the commands found here:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/openssl.html
and here: 
https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/enc.html

The command breakdown being:

- *openssl* - the OpenSSL base command
- *enc* - the command used to begin encrypting/decrypting
- *-d* - the tag used to specify decryption
- *-K* - the tag used to specify the use of a key file
- *key.txt* - the key file itself
- *-iv* - the tag used to specify the use of an accompanying initialization vector
- *iv.txt* - the IV file itself
- *-in* - the tag used to specify the input file
- *sample.encrypted* - the input file
- *-out* - the tag used to specify the output file
- *sample.decrypted* - the desired output file

As far as I can tell, the command works - the output file is generated, but its contents are not properly decrypted (it's just garbled text). I don't think there's anything wrong with the files that the client provided, but rather with my implementation of OpenSSL's commands to decrypt the file.

If anyone knows how to properly decrypt a file using provided Key and IV files, help would be greatly appreciated. I've been setting aside other responsibilities while Googling around trying to figure this out.

Comment: First of all, note that just calling a single command line utility is not considered programming here. Don't you mean string of 64 and 32 characters respectively? Are you sure the `-K` and `-iv` parameters are expecting files at all? What's the algorithm & mode of encryption?

Comment: There are *PBE* (password) options which use a file, but the very first words for `-K` and `-iv` on the manpage you link are "the actual key to use: ... as ... hex" and "the actual IV to use: ... as ... hex". If the actual key and IV are the contents of the files, you must put the contents of the files as the command arguments. And as @MaartenBodewes implies you need to specify a cipher and at least implicitly mode; with no cipher, `enc` neither encrypts nor decrypts, it merely copies and copied encrypted data is still encrypted and "garbled".